# Check content of JTextField then store in String to access from another class

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

I'm creating a Java application to allow users to insert data into a MySQL database through a GUI interface. It's structured by using a main class for all of the GUI then separate classes outside for each function (Create tables, Insert data etc).

I've created a function in the GUI section which checks when a user presses a JButton by using an actionListener, this then opens a JOptionPane which has a panel with some JTextfields in it, this proceeds into an if/else statement to check if the first JTextField has text in it (The rest of the data can be null). Once this process is complete it runs a getText on the JTextField and stores it in a string.

The main class:

```
package catalogue;

    addSupplier.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            //Call a JOptionPane and give it an int value to be able to check status of button presses without another ActionListner
            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, addSupplierPanel, "Please enter supplier name", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
            //Checks if OK button is pressed
            if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){

                //Check if user entered any text into suppNameIn (Cannot be null)
                if(suppNameIn.getText().equals("")){

                    //Dispense error as suppNameIn is empty
                    System.out.println("Pressed Okay, nothing entered");

                } else {

                    //Grab the text from the JTextField and convert it into a usable string
                    String suppNameInsert = suppNameIn.getText();
                    String suppCollectionInsert = suppCollectionIn.getText();

                    //Confirmation that data has been read in from JTextField correctly
                    System.out.println(suppNameInsert + " Successfully entered");
                    System.out.println(suppCollectionInsert + " Successfully entered");

                    try{
                        //Connect to DB
                        Connection conn = CatalogueDB.getConnection();
                        //Prepare statement to run the insert script using the strings as input variables
                        PreparedStatement posted = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO supplier (suppName, suppCollection) VALUES ('"+suppNameInsert+"', '"+suppCollectionInsert+"')");
                        //Push the PreparedStatement 'posted'
                        posted.executeUpdate();
                    //Catch if anything goes wrong while connecting to the database
                    } catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Error adding supplier");}
                    //Finish by printing a message to say the insert has worked.
                    finally{
                        System.out.println("Insert Completed.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The separate insertData class:

```
package catalogue;

import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class insertData {
    CatalogueUI.suppNameInsert;

    public void insertSupplier() throws Exception{
        try{
            //Connect to DB
            Connection conn = CatalogueDB.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement posted = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO supplier (suppName, suppCollection) VALUES ('"+suppNameInsert+"', '"+suppCollectionInsert+"')");
            posted.executeUpdate();
        } catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Error adding supplier");}
        finally{
            System.out.println("Insert Completed.");
        }
    }

}
```

The issue that I am having is that I cannot access the String outside of the main class. Am I building this in the incorrect way for what I want to achieve or am I having a separate issue than what I think I am?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot access the String outside of the main class

Of course. Classes work independently of others. A class has no idea what variables are being used in any other class.

If you want to create two classes then you need to pass parameters from one class to the other. This is no different then when you invoke a method and pass parameters to a method.

I would say there is no reason for a separate class. The SQL access would just be a method in your main class.

```
PreparedStatement posted = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO supplier (suppName, suppCollection) VALUES ('"+suppNameInsert+"', '"+suppCollectionInsert+"')");
```

Also, you are using a `PreparedStatement` incorrectly. The point of using a `PreparedStatement` is to pass parameters to the `PreparedStatement`. Using the `PreparedStatement` properly will make the above code easier to read and maintain.

See: [Using Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more information.

Comment: Also it would be a good idea to escape those variables to prevent SQL-Injection and other possible attacks.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! The reason I don't particularly want this insert stored in this class is that I am going to be creating a larger insert which has five inputs, I was going to configure that insert in a similar way to the one posted above and do if-else statements to ensure that the correct JTextFields have been occupied, I saw this getting large quickly and wanted a way to do it separately for the sake of easy reading.

Although I'm probably now just going to settle on keeping it in the main class now.

Comment: @NomadMaker That's a good point, I'll keep that in mind for any apps I make in the future, this project I am currently working on isn't going live, I'm just trying to learn some MySQL/JDBC implementation for future projects!